# cannot find mscorlib in portable class library

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mscorlib

I cannot find mscorlib when I right-click and say 'Add Reference'. I cannot find any of the core libraries.

I was targeting .net framework 4.0, windows phone and silverlight. This corresponds to profile 2. On checking the folder, mscorlib is present in profile 2.

I have installed .Net framework 4.0.3 and 4.5 on my system.

If someone could help me out I would appreciate it.

Sharpi.

Comment: It is an essential assembly, it contains the declarations for core types like System.Object and System.String.  You therefore cannot add or remove it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update Visual Studio recently?

Windows Libraries have a tendency of disappearing with Visual Studio Updates.

Last month I had upgraded to VS 2012 update 3 and my SQL.net libraries disappeared and the only way to bring them back was to rollback(reinstall) to update 1.

mscorlib library exists at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71".

Check if this path exists on your system and has the mscorlib.dll file.